# '(' or '[' expected compiling error under UNIX

Tags: java, unix, javac

Here's a piece of my code. It has no problem under windows.

`LinkedList<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();`

However in UNIX, `javac` gives "'(' or '[' expected" at the first angle bracket near `new LinkedList<TreeNode>`

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Which version of the compiler/compliancelevel is running on unix ???. If it is pre version 5, you would get this message

Comment: Yep has *nothing* to do with unix and all to do with Java version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do java -version on your unix box. If you don't get a 1.5+ version (which apparently is the case), generics won't be supported.

You should upgrade your JDK on Unix

Comment: Yep it's 1.4.2 What can I do if I can't upgrade it myself?

Comment: I think on Unix, it's as simple as extracting the zip file for whatever JDK you want to use in a subdirectory where you can write to. Say JDK/ in your home directory. So then you can call ~/JDK/bin/javac or ~/JDK/bin/java

Answer (score 1):

Probably on your UNIX machine there is still an old Java installed (before Java SE 5.0) that doesn't know [Generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).